# Creating JDBC Connections Outside The DAO

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jdbc, dao

So I just finished learning JDBC this weekend and have successfully transferred my code from the main method into an MVC app. The purpose of this application is to hold a roster of players and display a users credentials if requested. The program works great and when I request a url like...

```
http://localhost:8084/gmustudent/players?id=1
```

I get the correct output for that player! The problem is I am performing the database connection within my PlayersDAO class and I assume that this is not the "best" way to do this. So I have two questions.

1. Is there a way to perform the database connection within the web.xml
   file or some other file so that when the server is initially started it will
   immediately perform the connection to the database and be ready to
   query when asked?
2. And is this actually a better alternative to having the connection in the DAO or would this have unforeseen negative drawbacks. AKA would a constant connection to my database be exactly what I do not want?

Any comments or links would be greatly appreciated. And I'll share the code I currently have for my DAO class so that you can see what I have so far. Thank you all!

```
package com.jdbc.test;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class PlayersDAO 
{
    public static Players viewPlayer(int id) throws SQLException
    {
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Players playerObject = null;

        try
        {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmustudent";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "root";

            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException error)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM players WHERE id = " + id);

            if(resultSet.next())
                playerObject = new Players(resultSet.getLong("id"), resultSet.getString("name"), resultSet.getString("position"), resultSet.getString("height"), resultSet.getString("year"), resultSet.getString("hometown"), resultSet.getString("highschool"), resultSet.getString("headshot"));   
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null) try{connection.close();} catch(SQLException ignore) {}
            if (statement != null) try{statement.close();} catch(SQLException ignore) {}
            if (resultSet != null) try{resultSet.close();} catch(SQLException ignore) {}
        }

        return playerObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can configure `JNDI JDBC Resource` or use `JAP - Hibernate'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create database connection in web.xml file by using resource.  I hope this tutorial will help you.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/database-connection-pooling-tomcat-eclipse-db/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JDBC Connection Pooling](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html).It can provide significant benefits in terms of application performance, concurrency and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, its always a good approach to hide the instantiation details of any resources. You can use factory method to do this. The advantage of this approach is that you can always change the way to manage the resources - e.g. You can have one instance of JDBCConnection per DAO or you can have connection pool. Any time you can provide your development specific db connection, test specific db connection or production db connection. All these details you can hide doing such approach.